# How to solve API fetch and type error in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an error when I call an API, I think this error is failed to compile, because this error indicates to me:

```
Cannot read property 'type' of undefined in line 18
```

I run `fetchCoins` in `useEffect`, how to I can solve this error?
I dont know why `fetchCoins` is undefined!?

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Coin from './Coin';
import Pagination from 'react-js-pagination'

const App = () => {

  const [coins,setCoins] = useState([]);
  const [search , setSearch] = useState('');

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [postsPerPage] = useState(10);


useEffect(() => {
  const fetchCoins = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios.get('https://api............')
    .then(res => { setCoins(res.data)})
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    setLoading(false);
  };
  fetchCoins()
}, [])


  const handleChange = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
  }

  const filteredCoins = coins.filter(coin =>
    coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );

  console.log(fetchCoins())

  return (
    <div className="coin-app">
      <div className="coin-search"> 

      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="search" className="coin-input" onChange={handleChange} />
      </form>
    </div>
    {filteredCoins.map(coin => {
        return (
          <Coin
            key={coin.id}
            name={coin.name}
            price={coin.current_price}
            symbol={coin.symbol}
            marketcap={coin.total_volume}
            volume={coin.market_cap}
            image={coin.image}
            priceChange={coin.price_change_percentage_24h}
          />
        );
      })}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you share line 18 please? You're calling a type property of an undefined object and I can't see that in your code

Comment: You can't call `console.log(fetchCoins())` outside your `useEffect` because you used `const` which is block scoped. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: I would think that setLoading(false) would happen almost immediately after setLoading(true) due to the async nature of the part in between.

Comment: Yeah there are many issues here I can't focus on one :D

Comment: code looks good. Can you please share your line 18?

Comment: I think it's line 18 of some other file.  There is nothing here with a .type property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to `fetchCoins` outside `useEffect` because of `cost` block scope. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

You can fix that bit via the below code.

Your error around line 18 is not in this file and likely unrelated to your question.

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Coin from "./Coin";
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";

const App = () => {
  const [coins, setCoins] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [postsPerPage] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCoins = () => {
      setLoading(true);
      axios
        .get("https://api............")
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
        .then((res) => {
          setCoins(res.data);
          setLoading(false); // note I moved this in here
        });
    };
    fetchCoins();
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  const filteredCoins = coins.filter((coin) =>
    coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
  );

  console.log(coins); // you don't have access to fetchCoins here due to block scope limitations

  return (
    <div className="coin-app">
      <div className="coin-search">
        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="search"
            className="coin-input"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
      {filteredCoins.map((coin) => {
        return (
          <Coin
            key={coin.id}
            name={coin.name}
            price={coin.current_price}
            symbol={coin.symbol}
            marketcap={coin.total_volume}
            volume={coin.market_cap}
            image={coin.image}
            priceChange={coin.price_change_percentage_24h}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: move setLoading(false) inside .then promise and it was fixed, thanks